# How to add protocol handler in Linux

Tags: linux, debian

I am using a debian linux and would like to add a protocol handler for my program so you could all links as myapp://param and it would call `myapp param`

I tried this https://superuser.com/questions/162092/how-can-i-register-a-custom-protocol-with-xdg but I do not have the `mimeapps.list`.

How would I add a custom handler, would also be nice to know if there are any update tools (like for icon cache) that I can include in my `.deb` file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: As I do want to use it in a .deb file, imho it is about programming. Programming does not stop at the end of coding, its also about creating installers (which the deb file ist) and managing the resources, etc.